# Google Cloud Platform KVM Support

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtualization, kvm

I have just created a server in GCP. It is a Ubuntu that i want to use with GNS3. The problem is that machines created in GCP does not have KVM support. 
Is there sone way to use it in GCP?
Regards!!

Comment: What do you mean by KVM support?

Answer (score 6):

The GCP Compute Engine supports KVM virtualization module but isn't super clear about how to actually create the instance. Here is a concrete way to create a cloud instance that supports KVM.

```
gcloud compute instances create kvm1 \
    --zone=us-central1-a \
    --min-cpu-platform="Intel Haswell" \
    --image-project=ubuntu-os-cloud \
    --image=ubuntu-2004-focal-v20220610 \
    --boot-disk-size 200GB \
    --machine-type=n1-standard-16 \
    --enable-nested-virtualization
```

After creating the instance I SSHd into the machine to verify that KVM can be used:

```
>> ls /dev/kvm
/dev/kvm

>> egrep -c '(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfo
32

>> sudo apt install cpu-checker
>> sudo kvm-ok
INFO: /dev/kvm exists
KVM acceleration can be used
```

This worked for my use-case of building AOSP.

Answer (score 2):

For now GCP Compute Engine supports KVM based nested virtualization - check docs [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/enable-nested-virtualization-vm-instances).

Answer (score 0):

GCE doesn't have support for nested.

Comment: I don't think AWS does either. Azure might, but I don't know.